# PictureBox.Load Method add picture from website that requires authentication

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to add a picture to a PictureBox via the .Load() Method. The Problem with that picture is that it stays on a website which requires authentication!

Link is like: https://intranet.company.com/_layouts/15/company/PortraitHandler.ashx?isinternal=true&account=test/account

How can I fix this?

Comment: Depends how the site does authentication. For example if it uses cookies, you would need to download the image from C# using a webclient and provide authentication credentials, or cookies.

Comment: @RvdK I would like to do it via windows authentication. Using from the current user logged in to the machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
public Bitmap getImageFromURL(string sURL)
    {
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
        Request.Method = "GET";
        Request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Response.GetResponseStream());
        Response.Close();

        return bmp;
    }
```